# What is the proper way to call a class instance in c++?

Tags: c++, class

I'm beginner in c++ and I have a question about how to call a class instance...
I wrote a class in c++ but I don't know if I use the good way to call it .
I use a pointer in main , but is this the good way to do it ? I think it weird to have to use pointers but I don't manage to do the same without.

Thanks !

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class list_int{
    public:
        void run();
        list_int(): liste(){};
    private:
        void print_menu();
        void add_entier();
        void print_list();
        void suppr_last();
        void print_last();
        std::vector<int> liste;
};

void list_int::print_menu()
{
    std::cout<<"Menu :"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"1. Ajouter un entier"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"2. Afficher la liste des entiers"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"3. Supprimer dernier entier de la liste."<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"4. Afficher la dernière note tapée"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"5. Quitter"<<std::endl;
}

void list_int::add_entier()
{
    if(liste.size()>9)
    {
        std::cout<<"Liste remplie"<<std::endl;
        return;
    }
    int entier;
    std::cout<<"Entre l'entier a ajouter:";
    std::cin>>entier;
    liste.push_back(entier);
}

void list_int::print_list()
{
    std::cout<<"La liste :"<<std::endl;
    for(auto it=liste.begin();it!=liste.end();it++)
    {
        std::cout<<*it<<std::endl;
    }
}

void list_int::suppr_last()
{
    liste.pop_back();
    std::cout<<"Dernier element supprimé"<<std::endl;
}

void list_int::print_last()
{
    if(!liste.size())
    {
        std::cout<<"last element:"<<liste[liste.size()-1]<<std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cout<<"Liste vide"<<std::endl;
    }
}

void list_int::run()
{
    int choix;
    bool continuer = true;
    while(continuer)
    {
        print_menu();
        std::cin>>choix;
        switch(choix){
            case 1:
                add_entier();
                break;
            case 2:
                print_list();
                break;
            case 3:
                suppr_last();
                break;
            case 4:
                print_last();
                break;
            default:
                continuer = false;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    list_int* liste = new list_int();
    liste->run();
}
```

Comment: Don't know what you mean "call a class instance", sorry.

Comment: If you tried, `list_int liste();` you will have run afoul of a "Vexing Parse". This looks like a function declaration to the compiler rather than a variable definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no need to use pointers here; you can simply create a `list_int` object and call `run()` on it directly:

```
int main()
{
    list_int liste;
    liste.run();

    return 0; // (don't forget to return)
}
```

Also, when working with pointers in general, you should always make sure to `delete` your pointer after using it. So in your particular example, if you opted to keep the pointer, you'd have to call `delete liste` at the end.

Comment: The general order or preference goes: Use an Automatic allocation (as above answer), use a container, use a `std::unique_ptr` with `std::make_unique`, use a `std::shared_ptr` with `std::make_shared`, use a raw pointer with `new` and `delete` (as in question, sort of), use  `malloc`, with `free`. You should not move down the chain without a good reason and only after exhausting all reasonable alternatives. That said, the goal is readable, maintainable code that meets the project requirements, so find a balance. Don't over-complicate avoiding a less preferred option.